# Import and export data from SQL Server table using query

Tags: sql-server

I need to import and export data from a table using a SQL query so I need query example for importing and exporting data. I don't want to export it to txt file as the data is not getting aligned. I have read that this can done manually but I want to do this dynamically. You can see below manually import and export data.

[image]

Comment: You're about right in the menu, just need to use the option Generate Scripts -> script Tables -> choose what tables you need -> go to Advanced -> Types of data to script = Data Only. If the table is too big, I'm not sure Management Studio will be stable enough, but you'll see.

Comment: i dont want to generate any script of table or database.i want to import/export data using query. and i dont get any option of script in export data by manually.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. In this case, I think that your best friend is the [bcp utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx). That Export Data option is actually an [SSIS package](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141134.aspx). There may be other solutions, but bcp is the easiest to use. Maybe if you describe the problem for a more particular case it would be easier to get a working solution.

Comment: something like that but i want my tables data export into ms-excel.@Marian